# Displaying and Image on an Oracle Form

Tags: oracle

Can anyone tell me how to display an image on an oracle form and what is the best way to do so.

I am a beginner and creating my first database and can't see to be able to do so

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the source of the image is. If it's stored in the database, you should create an Image Item and load the contents of the image field just like you would do with any other type of item.

If it's an image file, you have to click on Edit->Import->Image... and select the file you need.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Only resized my GIF picture and it worked. File --> Import --> Image "select" the image.

Best of luck